# Relocating ".fig" files when creating a GUI using Matlab GUIDE

Tags: user-interface, matlab, relative-path, matlab-figure

I've developed a GUI for some build scripts, and am now in the process of deploying it. As the script will be deployed to a number of different machines at various points, I need to use the standard format of directories that the team use.

The GUI consists of a ".fig" file that contains the visual definition of the UI, and a m-script that defines the functionality. I need to locate these two in "fig/" and "m/" folders respectively, but I can't figure out how to. I first searched for an include statement of some kind in the m-script, as when I Run it on its own, the error message in the command window states that the ".fig" file can't be found, but there doesn't seem to be a reference to the ".fig" file anywhere, I assume that it's inferred as both files have the same name but a different extension.

I fear that Matlab's GUI system requires that both ".m" and ".fig" files are in the same location, but this will be an inelegant solution that I'd rather not go for if I can avoid it.

The next thing I'm going to try is to call a script that copies the fig file from the other directory to the same location as the m-script, when it is executed, then deletes that copy once the script exits, which again seems a clunky solution, but will allow me to adhere to the team's organisation conventions.

Does anyone else know of an undocumented means of specifying the relative location of a GUI ".fig" file?

Comment: Still ugly but possibly slightly less ugly, you might want to consider creating temporary OS softlinks rather than copying the .figs directly.  At least you won't ever have to worry about synchronization errors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've done similar on Linux in the past when linking to libraries; easy to map different versions when you can keep the folder reference the same and change a symlink.Unfortunately we're forced to run Microsoft software these days, which is a whole other battle...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export the GUIDE-generated GUI as a single `.m` file. Check out this blog post: [GUIDE GUIs in All One File](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2011/04/04/guide-guis-in-all-one-file/).

I'm not sure if this is a new feature, or one of those things that has always been there...

[image]

Comment: Superb, had no idea that you could do that! Instantly solved my problem.Thanks very much!