# How to change MATLAB GUIDE figure callbacks file name?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, matlab-guide

[MATLAB GUIDE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/bqz6p81.html) is a utility for GUI programming in MATLAB.

If designing a figure named `myfigure` it creates two files `myfigure.fig`, which contains the GUI layout description, and `myfigure.m` which contains the callbacks describing the logic behind the GUI (e.g. when you click a button, a certain function is being called, and the .m file is intended to contain codes of such callback functions).

How can I change the name of `myfigure.m` to `myfigure_callbacks.m` and still have the functions in `myfigure_callbacks.m` bound with the GUI described at `myfigure.fig`?

So I want to have files named

`myfigure.fig` and `myfigure_callbacks.m`

instead of

`myfigure.fig` and `myfigure.m`

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? Would a file system hardlink `myfigure_callbacks.m` -> `myfigure.m` be a solution for you?

Comment: Note that (a) you don't need to have your callbacks in the `.m`-file; you can write a file for each callback individually (or write a class etc), and that (b) the `.m`-file is how you call the GUI, i.e. instead of calling `myGUI`, you'd call `myGUI_callbacks`, which may confuse you in a few months.

Comment: @Vahagn: Another possibility is to export you GUI as a self-contained single M-file from GUIDE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6548189/relocating-fig-files-when-creating-a-gui-using-matlab-guide/6556947#6556947

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation this cannot be done.

> The code file and the FIG-file that define your GUI must have the same
>   name. This name is also the name of your GUI.

Here's the documentation from Mathworks: [Name a GUI and Its Files](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f11-998352.html).

---

**Edit:**
As you observed, renaming the GUI is intended to rename associated FIG and code files (automatically).

> To rename a GUI, rename the GUI FIG-file using Save As from the Layout
>   Editor File menu. When you do this, GUIDE renames both the FIG-file
>   and the GUI code file, updates any callback properties that contain
>   the old name to use the new name, and updates all instances of the
>   file name in the body of the code.